# Combine UIPickerView and UITableView

Tags: uitableview, swift, segue, uipickerview, uicontainerview

I'm trying to show information about a word in a UITableView. Originally I used labels in a view controller that were specifically spaced. Once I started using autolayout, that became too complex. That configuration also had the limitation of having a set amount of space to show info. Some of the information depends on the state of a UIPickerView. I tried putting a static table view in place of the labels but I got an error `Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances`. I tried to place the UITableView in a UITableView controller and embed that controller in a container view.

I don't know how to update the tableview contents when the picker view selection changes. I tried calling  `performSegueWithIdentifier("nounDetailTableViewSegue", sender: self)`which is the embed segue, at the end of the `func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {}` function with the hope of updating the labels in the static table view.

I never got it to work, so is there a correct way of doing this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution using the container view is too complicated. Its better to use a dynamic cell even if it's overkill.